# Pyautogui not working correctly ! Help me

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am having problem with python.I made a bot that plays games for me while I am doing something else.The bot is not working right.Below is the code.I am coding a game automater.The elif statement is not working,I have tried multiple times but still it doesnt work.I am using a function that performs a task when it sees a specific picture even when the picture is one the screen it doesnt work.The elif is not working but when it sees the picture the code doesnt do anything.I have channged the code multiple times looking for answers but it is still not working.I hope someone helps me because this is important.
Edited It works now!!! thanks to everyone that answered.Special thanks to Chakib37 it worked

```
import pyautogui,time 
pyautogui.click(610,753)
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('C:/Users/E7440/Desktop/playable.png',confidence = 0.6) != None:
         pyautogui.click(626,307)
         time.sleep(3)
         pyautogui.click(713,610)
         time.sleep(1)
         pyautogui.click(729,648)
         time.sleep(5)
         pyautogui.click(580,447)
         time.sleep(0.5)
         pyautogui.click(665,444)
         time.sleep(0.5)
         pyautogui.click(750,445)
         time.sleep(0.5)
         pyautogui.click(662,695)
         time.sleep(60)
         while True:
               if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('C:/Users/E7440/Desktop/Class 7/Science/ok.png',confidence = 0.6) != None:
                pyautogui.click(632,690)
                time.sleep(4)
                pyautogui.click(819,690)
                time.sleep(1)
                pyautogui.click(753,690)
                time.sleep(6)
    elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen('C:/Users\E7440/Desktop/skip.png',confidence = 0.6) != False:
           pyautogui.click(626,307)
           print("Found the right one")
           time.sleep(10)
           pyautogui.click(795,52)
           time.sleep(5)
```

It is made by pyautogui.

Comment: Please update your question and title to outline what you mean by "is not working right". What is is supposed to be doing that it is not? Or what is it not doing that it should?

Comment: Could you please specify what specifically is not working right? Right now, it's hard to solve the problem, since we don't know that the problem is.

Comment: done it now,I started coding 4 months ago so I am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

I think it should at least describe what it's supposed to be doing, also on line 28 LocateOnScreen it supposed to be comparing to None instead of False.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).